# How do I do model versioning with AutoMLImageTrainingJobRunOp?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

I know in Vertex AI you can version models. You can eg upload a model and set its `parent_model`:

```
model_v2 = aip.Model.upload(parent_model=model_v1.resource_name,...
```

And I know in the GUI you can create an AutoML model that is a version of an existing one, but how do you do it in code?

In a pipeline I use `AutoMLImageTrainingJobRunOp` but it does not have a `parent_model` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable model versioning using the below code snippet:

```
    from google.cloud import aiplatform
    DISPLAY_NAME = "model_name"
    models = aiplatform.Model.list(filter=("display_name={}").format(DISPLAY_NAME))
  
    if len(models) == 0:
      model_upload = aiplatform.Model.upload(
        display_name = DISPLAY_NAME, # Your model display name
        version_description="Add model description here", #Add model description
        version_aliases=["v1"], # Create Model Alias
        labels={"release": "dev"}, #Label your model
        artifact_uri = model.uri[:-6], 
        ... 
      )
    else:
        parent_model = models[0].resource_name
        version_id = models[0].version_id
        model_upload = aiplatform.Model.upload(
            display_name = DISPLAY_NAME, 
            ...,  
            parent_model = parent_model
        )
```

There are other parameters also mentioned in the code for serving containers, you can remove them if you don't need that.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not uploading I'm using automl.